# python __getattribute__ RecursionError when returning class variable attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, getattr, getattribute

Why does Foo2 result in infinite recursion calling `getattr` of a class variable in `__getattribute__`, but Foo works fine making the same call in `__getattr__`? Any suggestions on how to get Foo2 to work?

```
class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bar = 5

    def getbar(self):
        return self.bar


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__foo = Foobar()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.__foo, attr)


class Foo2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__foo = Foobar()

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return getattr(self.__foo, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            super().__getattribute__(attr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo2 = Foo2()
    print(foo.bar, foo.getbar())  # Works as expected
    try:
        print(foo2.bar, foo2.getbar())  # Doesn't work
    except RecursionError:
        print('Why does Foo2 result in RecursionError. How to fix?')
```

Setup: Windows 10, Python 3.7

Comment: For Foo2, it should read `__getattr__` instead of `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__getattribute__` method is called unconditionally to look up all attributes on an object, not only ones that don't exist (which is what `__getattr__` does). When you do `self.__foo` in its implementation, you recurse, since `__foo` is another attribute that we're trying to look up on the object.

To avoid this issue, you need to call your parent's `__getattribute__` method to get all of your own attributes inside the `__getattribute__` method:

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    try:
        return getattr(super().__getattribute__("_Foo__foo"), attr)
    except AttributeError:
        super().__getattribute__(attr)
```

Note that I had to manually apply name mangling to the `__foo` attribute, because we need to pass the name as a string to `super().__getattribute__`. That probably suggests you shouldn't be doing the mangling in the first place. A name with a single leading underscore might be a better choice.

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind that self.__foo was doing an attribute lookup. This does solve the problem. I'm guessing `__getattr__`, as in Foo, is probably the cleaner/safer option.