# Format class attributes with __getattribute__ overriding

Tags: python

I try to override the`__getattribute__` special method in a dataclass in order to get a formatted version of an attribute.

```py
@dataclass
class _BaseRouteRegistry:
    VERSION = '1'
    USERS = 'users'

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        route = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        return f"/api/{route}/v{self.VERSION}"

BaseRouteRegistry = _BaseRouteRegistry()

print(BaseRouteRegistry.USERS)
```

But I got a  `RecursionError`. Where I expected to get in the output: `/api/users/v1`

What I **don't get** if I directly return the `object.__getattribute__(self, item)` like so :

```py
@dataclass
class _BaseRouteRegistry:
    VERSION = '1'
    USERS = 'users'

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)

BaseRouteRegistry = _BaseRouteRegistry()

print(BaseRouteRegistry.USERS)
```

But then I just got `users` in output (of course not formatted since I removed the format string expression)

I saw many other answers on the `RecusrionError` like those ones :

[How do I implement __getattribute__ without an infinite recursion error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371753/how-do-i-implement-getattribute-without-an-infinite-recursion-error)

[python __getattribute__ RecursionError when returning class variable attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412943/python-getattribute-recursionerror-when-returning-class-variable-attribute)

In those questions above, they suggest to use the unbounded `object.__getattribute__(self, item)`.

I do understand why, and I tried to use it.

But in my example, since I need to return a formatted version of the attribute, I first need to retrieve it and only then return the formatted version.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got an infinite recursion when you try to access `self.VERSION` here `f"/api/{route}/v{self.VERSION}"` because `self.VERSION` also invokes `__getattribute__` method

So, you should handle `VERSION` attribute separately

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class _BaseRouteRegistry:
    VERSION = '1'
    USERS = 'users'

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item == "VERSION":
            return object.__getattribute__(self, item)

        route = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        return f"/api/{route}/v{self.VERSION}"

BaseRouteRegistry = _BaseRouteRegistry()

print(BaseRouteRegistry.USERS)
```

```
> /api/users/v1
```

Comment: Of course ! How didn't I see this ! Thanks a lot. By the way I will simply put the Version out of the class and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Eugenij's answer explains the issue with your code and how to fix it. However, if the goal is to control access to a specific attribute `USERS`, then you don't need to override `__getattribute__()` which affects access to all attributes. Instead, you can make `USERS` a property:

```
class _BaseRouteRegistry:
    VERSION = '1'
    _USERS = 'users'
    
    @property
    def USERS(self):
        return f"/api/{self._USERS}/v{self.VERSION}"

BaseRouteRegistry = _BaseRouteRegistry()

print(BaseRouteRegistry.USERS)
```

Comment: Upvote for the answer but this is exactly what I expect (affect the access of each attributes so @Eugenji 's answer is correct for me). Thanks